# Problems installing .ppd files (PERL) from CronW v2.0

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks, perl

I wanna test [CronW](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) to have some (acceptable) task scheduler under Windows XP, but after installing the v2.0 .exe and the .msi of ActivePerl v5.16.3 (both 32 bits), the next step of installation (according to its included [Installation.txt](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/install.html) file) fails:

```
C:\CRONw>ppm install -noforce -follow modules\Win32-Daemon.ppd
Usage:  ppm install [--force] [--nodeps] [--area <area>] <module> | <url> | <file> | <num>
        Run 'ppm help install' to learn more.
```

I have tried:

```
C:\CRONw>ppm install modules\Win32-Daemon.ppd
ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform
```

As you can see, I am new to PERL.
Maybe I have to use another version of PERL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should mean the provided module are for a different architecture (ie "x86_64") or perl version.

Stick to yours, the required modules are quite standard, so just install them through your ppm, but targeting ActiveState ppm repository.

There is also a GUI interface to the "Perl Package Manager" (aka "ppm"), you can find it in the "All Programs" Perl menu item.

In the "all packages" view, filter to Win32-Daemon, mark it for install:

[image]

Finally run the marked actions (small green right arrow) to install the package.

You can also select all your wanted modules, launch the install. "ppm" will also select any prerequisites as needed.

Comment: your GUI idea went fine, thanks you. But what do you mean for "targeting ActiveState ppm repository"?

Comment: You don´t need to worry about this, as this is the default setting. The default "ppm repository" is the one set by ActiveState.

Comment: With PPM 4.19 following these steps, I can't filter Win32-Daemon, it just isn't listed =/ Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Metafaniel: I think this depends more about your Perl version, not the version of ppm you are using. I had a quick look at [Win32-Daemon ppm from ActiveState](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/Win32-Daemon/) and it appears that it is **not** provided for 5.18 Perl (but for 5.16 or 5.20 have it).

Comment: That was the reason! With ´ActivePerl-5.20´ I managed to install `Win32-Daemon` sucessfully. THANKS =)